Equivalence of derived categories
I was reading the proof of Proposition 1.7.11 in Kashiwara and Schapira's book Sheaves on Manifolds.

First, it claims that $D^+(\mathscr{C}')$ is a full subcategory of $D_{\mathscr{C}'}^+(\mathscr{C})$, which follows Proposition 1.6.5:

However, I don't know why it satisfies the condition (i) or (ii). The confusing part is that if we have a quasi-isomorphism $Y\rightarrow X$ with $X$ an object in $K^+(\mathscr{C})$ and $Y$ an object in $K^+(\mathscr{C'})$, we can take $\tau^{\ge n}(X)$ to get a quasi-isomorphism $X\rightarrow \tau^{\ge n}(X)$, but $\tau^{\ge n}(X)$ is not in $K^+(\mathscr{C}')$.
Furthermore, I don't understand what the morphism $M\rightarrow H^{p+1}(X)$ in line 10 of the proof is and why $M$ belongs to $\mathcal{C}'$.
Thanks for any help.
